# How can I reset the password on dd-wrt (buffallo 300nh router)

Tags: dd-wrt

How can I reset the password on dd-wrt (buffallo 300nh router)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to save any of the settings, you should be able to reset the password by pressing and holding the reset button on the backside of the router for 30 seconds, continuing to hold it while removing the power cord, then putting back in the power cord and continuing to hold the button for another 30 seconds. After that, it should be back to its default settings, including a blank password.

[Full details](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Reset_And_Reboot) on the different types of resets are available on DD-WRT's documentation pages.

Comment: so that won't wipe my dd-wrt right?

Comment: Correct. It will restore DD-WRT to its default settings, but will not remove DD-WRT from your router. It will however erase any wifi settings you've configured, DNS or PPPoE settings you've added, etc.